# When lauching a new tab - How to have certain commands given - VIM

Tags: vim, nerdtree

I have nerdtree plugin installed with my vim. This nerdTree gets activated when I press `Ctrl + n`
Now what i want is when i press `t` on a file in the nerd tree window it is launched in a new tab. Is there a way for me to set the t option so that when i press t and the file is opened in a new tab the command `Ctrl + n` is also passed and there is a new nerd tree window in that tab ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is the [NERDTree-tabs](https://github.com/jistr/vim-nerdtree-tabs) plugin, which is designed for exactly this reason. It's a small extension of NERDTree.

In short, it makes NERDTree tab-aware. If you have multiple tabs open, your NERDTree will either be open in all of them or closed in all of them.

Comment: Ill give that a try and post back